# Possible way to find Username from 1000,000 Users entries

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have Db of `100,000` users in MYSQL.  In that DB i am having column `ID,username,Fname,Lname`, etc.. 
When `www.example.com/Jim` or `www.example.com/123` (Where `JIM` is username and `123` is ID in the users table)

I am using MYSQL query : `select * from users where ID = 123 OR username = Jim` 
I am executing above query in PHP. 
Output of the above query is :

```
| ID | Username | fname  | lname   |
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|123 |   jim    |  Jim   | Jonson  |
```

My Problem is its taking huge time to select username or ID in the DB.

I have used following query

`SELECT * FROM`users`USE INDEX (UsersIndexId) where id=123`

Is this right way to call Index ?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE ID =327
```

OP

```
id  select_type  table    type    possible_keys        key      key_len ref rows Extra 
1     SIMPLE       users  Const  PRIMARY,UsersIndexId  PRIMARY     4   const
```

1

Comment: What are your index's ?

Post the output from explain select * from users where ID = 123 OR username = Jim

Comment: Indexing, Caching....there are many ways to improve performance. What have you tried?

Comment: If you dont already have indexes on ID and username I suggest adding them.

Comment: Hmmm I tried nothing .. I am trying search Best possible way to select username

Comment: @StevenFarley Can Link me for indexes ? I am using ID as Index (Primary key)

Comment: @SandeepKamble Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables it will help you to add indexes to your tables.

Comment: You need to decide if the username or the ID was passed and just search on one, not both. Should be easy since your user ID is numeric.

Comment: @MrCode In php code i am obvious searching only one . :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sugest you take a look at this: [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Quoting from the first paragraph:

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.
>   Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
>   through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
>   table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns
>   in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in
>   the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data. If
>   a table has 1,000 rows, this is at least 100 times faster than reading
>   sequentially.

That should help speed up your search.

(*Edit*: Updated the link to a newer version of the SQL docs)

PS: More specifically, [column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html) might be what you want.
You can find more info about adding indexes here: [Create Index Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)

Comment: I think i am going to add the Indexes . Thanks for the information .

Answer (score 2):

To complete @Kjartan answer, you can try the following :

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX id_i (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX username_i (`Username`);
```

Your queries should be faster.

Comment: Hmm I think It will take more storage ?

Comment: Of course it will take more storage! That is the trade off with indexes - more storage, more overhead to add and change data, but potential for much, much faster retrieval.

Comment: ID should be PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX

Comment: SELECT * FROM `users` USE INDEX (UsersIndexId) where id=123 Is this right way to call it ?

Comment: No need to `USE INDEX`, MySQL will do it automatically. Use `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users ...` to see if your indexes are uused by MySQL correctly.