# SQL query response time vs table size

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that is being accessed by a web browser. The query is pretty simple.

select * from table where ID="string"

the question I need to ask is that do I need to worry about the response time becoming "very noticeably" slower to the end user as the server grows large??

(right now the query is returned in 0.00004 seconds. i really dont care even if it takes a few seconds.)

Comment: what do you mean for very large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `ID` is the `primary key` for that table - no you don't have to worry about that query. Also if it's not your `primary key` but you've added an index ([How do I add indices to MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)) it will be also fine.

Make sure you're protecting yourself again SQL Injection ([How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) so don't directly insert your `path`-parameter or `query`-parameter into your SQL query.

Comment: thank you, the Id is not the primary key, the primary key is just a AI number. I will look into adding an index and i have protected against sql injection.

Comment: Also I just indexed my table (using your link, thank you) with the command ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (ID). How do I confirm that everything went well? all i got was "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0276 seconds.)"

Answer (score 1):

As long as the id column is indexed, no, you do not really have to worry about this particular query.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to worry about it. I have a table with roughly a billion rows and it returns immediately.

```
mysql> show profiles;
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                       |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00020500 | select * from xxxx where id = 768273542     |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is your id the primary key in the above example?

Comment: Yes, the id is the primary key.