# mysql index inserting updating

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a table with a `primary_key` and an `Integer` and I want to index the `Integer`, how would I do that?

Also, when I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` a row do I have to reindex or is this done automatically? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: (1) You would create an index on the column; (2) Databases maintain the indexes, so there is no need to "re-index" (although de-fragmenting is sometimes desirable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add indexes to MySQL tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! Also, when I use `WHERE` on the indexed column do I have to state that it's indexed?

Comment: @TrevorWood . . . You don't need to.  That is one thing that the query compiler/optimizer does.