# PHP mysql query taking too long for using like to timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this query :

```
 select field from table1 where time LIKE '%2016-03%' order by time asc limit 1
```

My problem is that the  table has thousands of rows and so it takes too long to search for 1 row. Is it normal?

Comment: There are more efficient ways of searching than using LIKE. What is the format of the field you're searching?

Comment: How about `select field from table1 where month(time) = 3 and year(time) = 2016`?

Comment: post the DDL for your table so we can determine if the issue is with the indexing.

Comment: Why can't you say `>= '2016-03-01' and < '2016-04-01'`?

Comment: @chris85 - I would agree with that solution.

Comment: @chris85 Try avoiding functions in queries as much as possible to allow the cache and optimization do the job the best way possible.

Comment: @Canis Exact comparison should be faster than wildcard matching.

Comment: @chris85 That is true for the first time the query runs, but in a setup where the cache can do its job, the functions defeats its purpose as the cache never caches queries with functions due to the result from the function possibly varying between subsequent calls.

Comment: @chris85 - thats not 100% correct. The Query Cache if not use when you use non-deterministic functions. Rhis Functions are not cached: BENCHMARK() CONNECTION_ID()
CONVERT_TZ() CURDATE()
CURRENT_DATE() CURRENT_TIME()
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() CURTIME()
DATABASE() ENCRYPT() (one parameter)
FOUND_ROWS() GET_LOCK()
LAST_INSERT_ID() LOAD_FILE()
MASTER_POS_WAIT() NOW()
RAND() RELEASE_LOCK()
SLEEP() SYSDATE()
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() (no parameters) USER()
UUID() UUID_SHORT()
See: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/query-cache/

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` queries are always going to be slower than looking for a specific value.

It'll help immensely to add an `INDEX` on the field and change your query to `LIKE '2016-03%'` (there won't ever be anything ***before*** the year in a timestamp so drop that first `%`). It'll be able to take a couple shortcuts, at least.

Comment: technically, it's only `like '%...'` and `like '%...%'` that are slow. `like '...%'` can still use string indexes for the portion at the start of the like pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `INDEX` to your `time` column and as other have pointed out, remove the leading `%` from the query.

[See this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)

Comment: no point. `%...%` like matches can't use indexes, no matter what kindd of index you slap on there.

Comment: @MarcB ah, thats right, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LIKE and starts with % MySQL must make a FULL TABLE SCAN to find the correct Dates, but if you start direct with the year they can use a index : ... KIKE '2016-03-%'