# PDO - What is wrong with this query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `saved_feed_".$_SESSION['id']."` (title,description,link,pub_date,img_link) VALUES (:?,:?,:?,:?,:?)";
echo $query;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$desc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$link,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$pub_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5,$img_link,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
echo $title.'<br>'.$desc.'<br>'.$link.'<br>'.$pub_date.'<br>'.$img_link;
```

> **Hint:** `$_SESSION['id']` value of the code above is 23 in this case.

The variable are all set, in fact if I `echo` them I can see all the values, but in the database nothing happen.

**This is a screenshot of the table**

[image]

Comment: First echo the query and then try to run the query directly in database(phpmyadmin) and see what happen

Comment: Remove `:` before `?`

Comment: Parameters are notated by eiter `?,?,?` or `:name1, :name2, :name3`

Comment: Saty is right..thanks, my distraction..

Comment: Putting arbitrary data in there is super dangerous. Be extremely careful when adding column names in that manner. If you can, test against a white-list of known-good columns and refuse to execute any query that doesn't conform. It's worth mentioning that naming your placeholders helps a lot, you can just `execute` given an `array()` of name-value pairs.

Comment: but with the bindParam() function it isn't secure? Sorry but i don't know much about security with php...
Maybe i don't understand you exactly (my english isn't good), can you make me an example please?

Comment: Why in the world are you creating a separate table per session ?!?!

Comment: Because i haven't learnded the diffence between create a single table with a lot of data with foreign key and a table for any session (1 user = 1 session)

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola You don't even need any foreign keys here. You just need to create another column (`session_id`) and set that to the session ID instead of creating an individual table per session.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes but it i create a very very long table with all the session id inside associated with the other content..is faster for the query to find a data inside this instead of search data directly on a table with only the user data inside?

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola It's absolutely not faster to create an individual table. [Simply index your session_id column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables) and everything will be blazing fast unless you have literally millions/billions of rows (in which your "individual tables" would fail hard WAY before that)