# PHP MYSQL - Reducing length time of query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

- Business
- Categories

Each business has a category and there are currently 10k+ businesses with different categories. I'm trying to find all of the businesses that have the category of 'Restaurant' using Laravel and MYSQL.

The code that I am using is below:

```
  $businesses = Business::join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'businesses.category')
              ->where('category.name', '=', $cat)->get();
```

Which, when `$cat` = 'Restaurant' brings back: `3183` results.

The issue is that at it's lowest, it's taking 8.9 seconds to 12 seconds to find any results. Can anyone suggest a way or where I'm going wrong which can improve how long this query takes to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that there are indexes on `category.id` and `businesses.category` to improve join speed , and `category.name` to speed the where.

Comment: Thanks! Can you offer any advice on how to update my table(s) with indexes?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables. Also be aware that adding indexes to tables makes the tables both larger and slower to update. It's all a balancing act.