# How to apply index for datetime field in sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete the record from the specific date range .

So I have used the below query

```
delete from `table_name` where `date`<1580947200
```

I have used datetime as data type for the `date` column

It takes long time to execute and sometimes it gets stuck while executing this query.

Can anyone say how to apply index for this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not indexing. Your issue is that your telling MySQL to *numerically* compare a non-numeric (DATETIME) column against a numeric value (Unix timestamp).

> i have used datetime as datatype for date column

This means the column is a `DATETIME` column. But;

> 1580947200

looks to me like a Unix Timestamp value.

Unix Timestamp is **not the same** as a MySQL DateTime entity.

Therefore; you need to CAST these two types to the same for the comparison; To do this you can use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) MySQL Function.

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) < 1580947200
```

---

If you do wish to add an index to the `date` column you can [read this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indices-to-mysql-tables).