# randomized code in mysql database

Tags: mysql, random, key

I think I'd better ask this question instead of guessing around without any experiment.

We are planning to add a new column as code

The code needs to have the following features:

1. It has to be unique.
2. Better to be a string, it's much easier for us to migrate data
3. Has to be random with enough space to avoid collision.

I am planning to just use UUID.

```
create table code(
  id char(36),
  unique index index1 (id)
) type=innodb;
```

Our operation behavior:

1. insert new code (at most 20K every day)
2. get row by code (very heavily, we may need to get every row in the database in limited time like 10 minutes).

Now I am worry about performance a little bit. We already have 400K row in our database. In the future it could grow to 10M or 30M.

Do you have any suggestion or see any problem?

BTW: I am not able to use auto incremented int because it's not randomized.

Comment: Not one part of a UUIDs is random. They are 100% calculated. You will get collisions with random. You'll get better answers if you provide more details. Why random? What else is in the row data? How big?

Comment: No. UUIDs *can* be generated. Or they can be random. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html (Version 4)

Comment: And no, there won't be any collisions. UUID uses SecureRandom to generate 16 random bytes. Even if there are 30M entries the chance for a collision is about 1 over 10^31

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead. You won't get any problems neither with mysql nor with UUID.

UUIDs generated randomly have enough states that there will be *for certain* no collision. (Indeed it's still a chance but its 1 over 10^31 in case of 30M entries.)

On the other Hand: Why bother with uuid (which divides your random in 5 groups with no sense at all) when you can as easily use SecureRandom to just generate 16 byte values and use them?

According to this answer: [How to store uuid as number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number) it is faster to store them in binary in mysq.

You want to read this, too: [UUID performance in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365132/uuid-performance-in-mysql/2365176)

When using mysql you should think about concepts for backup. Mysql will handle big databases quiet easily, but exporting/importing 30M rows can take some time.

For mysql row limits see this question: [How many rows in a database are TOO MANY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926079/how-many-rows-in-a-database-are-too-many)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest not to use MySQL for these cases (at least not the main storage that you actively search from).

There are number of different other technologies such as:

- Apache Lucene
- Apache Solr
- Elastic Search
- and more others...

These tools are build for fast searches on big data sets. It the above look like overkill you might simply use one of the NoSQL dbs, it will give you much more performance in your case.

There are huge number of articles comparing performance and limitation between all of these.