# Storing language dictionaries in database

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary

I'm creating a language app that currently only features Mandarin Chinese and Spanish.

Currently, I have self-created dictionary simply loaded as JSON without storing in the DB, but I've found full downloadable dictionaries, such as [CEDICT for Chinese](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/) to do the definitions for me. That being said, this file is 115k rows long, with 6 columns per row.

I also need to do this for Spanish, and then every other language I plan on including.

Notes:

- MySQL DB
- Laravel ORM (PHP)

That being said, what's the best way to store this data?

I'm assuming as separate tables, `dictionary_zh`, `dictionary_es`, but I could also store each dictionary in a dictionary table, with an added column for `locale` and query based on that. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926079/how-many-rows-in-a-database-are-too-many) states that 1m records isn't "too much" for a table to handle, it simply defines on how you index the table.

---

Btw, anyone have a recommendation for a good downloadable Spanish - English dictionary?

---

**Note**: I'm downloading the dictionary and cutting it up into something I can load into a CSV

```
Traditional Simplified  Pinyin  Meaning       Level Quest
佟               佟       Tong2   surname Tong    1     2
...
```

I'm translating it by simply passing in the identifying character, in this case`佟`, and grabbing its Meaning.

Comment: keep your dictionaries separate, you'll have to maintain changes-only updates later as they update the data. have an interface programmed the same way for all dictionaries, something like `$dictionaryObj->translate( $term )`. This is so that you will have a simple way to translate. 

If you tell us more about how the translation works, I can try and give you more of my feedback.

Comment: @VladimirGhetau see above

Answer (score 1):

I would store each dictionary in a separate table to abstract how I fetch the definition for a word depending on the locale, without the need to know how a dictionary (mapped as `Dictionary` type in the diagram below) operates its translation. This is useful when you might have dictionaries which don't reside in your DB, such as ones translating via an API.

[image: UML]

The method `translate()` is implemented differently for each type of `Dictionary` (in your case `ChineseDictionary` or `SpanishDictionary`).

Another advantage of this approach from a data management point of view is that you will not have to make a lot of operations on the data when new versions of your dictionary are released, which makes it cheap to maintain.