# Summarize points in MySQL table by player id in last month and replace with ONE record

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a simple game: players earn points, what I store in the POINTS table. I'm afraid the table will be too big, so I want to summarize the points of last month because optimalizing.

For example ID 42 player has got 120 records in the table between 01.08.2019 and 31.08.2019, with 560 points. I would like to delete the 120 rows, and insert only one, with 560 points. I am using PHP(5.6.40) and MySQL.

I have no idea how to solve it. Should I make an archive table, copy the records to it from original table, delete the copied records from original table, and insert back the summarized records only?

### POINTS table

id : auto inc. int
timestamp : (unsigned) int
playerid : int
points : tinyint

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. It's harder to maintain the system and debug the system. Optimize the parts that are slow when they are slow. :-)
There are people with millions of rows and no problems (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995078/3103271). Keep in mind, that an int is only some bytes. Even with 2^30 records it only needs some GB space.

Answer (score 2):

Do not delete the data from your tables unless there is a very good reason to do so. You want to keep all the data and aggregate it in some other way. What if you make a mistake or a bug and you would like to recalculate the scores?

Generally the SQL aggregate function `SUM(score)` works really well with indexes and you might have thousands of rows and sum them up on the fly with no perceivable performance reduction.

If you expect a lot of rows in your table you could create an aggregate table and keep the summed up values in it. For example add another column to your `players` table called `total_score` and every new record you add for that player in `points` table will be added to the running total of `total_score`. You could handle this in your application layer or use DB triggers to update the totals automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate table for one maintaining summary of points. Do not delete the master table as it will serve as a point of reference in future if something goes wrong.

Create new table with same structure

```
CREATE table points_sum LIKE points
```

Then do one time cleaning to summarize points

```
INSERT INTO points_sum VALUES (
     SELECT id, timestamp, playerid, SUM(points) AS points
     FROM points
     GROUP BY playerid, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y-%m')
)
```

Later all values you store should be summed up before inserting/updating into the table. If player information is not present for the current month, then `INSERT` else `UPDATE`. Insert is pretty simple. Here is how you would update it.

```
UPDATE points_sum
SET points = points + 50 
WHERE playerid = '123'
AND timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-01 00:00:00')
AND timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-31 23:59:59')
```